# Julia - Invalid escape sequence triggered by a display equation

Tags: string, escaping, latex, julia, documentation

The Julia [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/documentation/index.html) says:

> Large LaTeX equations that do not fit inline within a paragraph may be
>   written as display equations using a fenced code block with the
>   "language" math as in the example below.

````
```math
f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\alpha+R\cos(\theta))d\theta
```
````

However, in one of my projects, the inline math expression seems to trigger an "invalid escape sequence" error:

````
"""
...


```math
G_u \sim PY(d_{|u|}, \theta_{|u|}, G_{\pi(u)})
```

...
"""
````

Did I understand the usage of display equations in documentation incorrectly?

The Julia version is 0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have escape sequence in the string so you can use either `raw` string:

````
julia> s = raw"""
       ```math
       G_u \sim PY(d_{|u|}, \theta_{|u|}, G_{\pi(u)})
       ```
       """
"```math\nG_u \\sim PY(d_{|u|}, \\theta_{|u|}, G_{\\pi(u)})\n```\n"

julia> println(s)
```math
G_u \sim PY(d_{|u|}, \theta_{|u|}, G_{\pi(u)})
```
````

or escape `\` (this is less convenient):

````
julia> s = """
       ```math
       G_u \\sim PY(d_{|u|}, \\theta_{|u|}, G_{\\pi(u)})
       ```
       """
"```math\nG_u \\sim PY(d_{|u|}, \\theta_{|u|}, G_{\\pi(u)})\n```\n"

julia> println(s)
```math
G_u \sim PY(d_{|u|}, \theta_{|u|}, G_{\pi(u)})
```
````

Finally if you use `Markdown` module you can use `doc` string like this:

````
julia> using Markdown

julia> s = doc"""
       ```math
       G_u \sim PY(d_{|u|}, \theta_{|u|}, G_{\pi(u)})
       ```
       """
G_u \sim PY(d_{|u|}, \theta_{|u|}, G_{\pi(u)})

julia> println(s)
$$
G_u \sim PY(d_{|u|}, \theta_{|u|}, G_{\pi(u)})
$$
````

EDIT: Now observe that `doc` wraps math with `$$` as presented above. Also `doc` only handles only `$` and `\` so e.g. interpolation works within `doc` as opposed to `raw` which is as raw as possible :). Finally `doc` does not produce a string but `Markdown.MD` object. For instance:

```
julia> using Markdown

julia> raw"""$x = 1"""
"\$x = 1"

julia> doc"""$x = 1"""
1

  = 1

julia> """$x = 1"""
"1 = 1"

julia> typeof(doc"""$x = 1""")
Markdown.MD
```

Comment: Thanks. The documentation doesn't seem to be very clear on this. The examples all start with `'''` without `raw` or `doc`. Are there any pros and cons with `using Markdown` compared to using `raw`?

Comment: I will add more explanation in the answer.